# orientdb sql api edge creation not visible in gremlin

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I have situation where I insert an edge via console.sh, but the edge does not seem to get attached to the vertex when I query from gremlin.sh.

First, create classes via sql / console.sh:

```
CREATE CLASS BaseV ABSTRACT EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY BaseV.class  STRING
CREATE PROPERTY BaseV.ID  STRING
CREATE INDEX BaseV.class NOTUNIQUE
CREATE INDEX BaseV.ID NOTUNIQUE
CREATE INDEX BaseVIdx ON BaseV (class, ID) UNIQUE 

CREATE CLASS BaseE ABSTRACT EXTENDS E
CREATE PROPERTY BaseE.class  STRING
CREATE PROPERTY BaseE.ID  STRING
CREATE INDEX BaseE.class NOTUNIQUE
CREATE INDEX BaseE.ID NOTUNIQUE
CREATE INDEX BaseEIdx ON BaseE (class, ID) UNIQUE 

CREATE CLASS User EXTENDS BaseV
CREATE CLASS Comment EXTENDS BaseV
CREATE CLASS Liked EXTENDS BaseE
```

Create test vertices and an edge gremlin:

```
gremlin> g.addVertex('class:User', [class: 'User', ID: '1'])
==>v(testUser)[#-1:-2]
gremlin> g.addVertex('class:Comment', [class: 'Comment', ID: '1'])
==>v(testComment)[#-1:-2]
gremlin> g.commit()
==>null
gremlin> g.V()
==>v(testUser)[#12:0]
==>v(testComment)[#13:0]
gremlin> g.addEdge('class:Liked', g.v('#12:0'), g.v('#13:0'), 'Liked')
==>e[#-1:-2][#12:0-Liked->#13:0]

gremlin> g.commit()
gremlin> g.V()
==>v(testUser)[#12:0]
==>v(testComment)[#13:0]
gremlin> g.V().out
==>v(testComment)[#13:0]
```

The edge is there, and available via g.V().out.  Now, insert an edge via the SQL update/upsert api (console.sh):

```
orientdb> select * from Liked

----+-----+------+-----+-----
#   |@RID |@CLASS|out  |in   
----+-----+------+-----+-----
0   |#14:0|Liked |#12:0|#13:0
----+-----+------+-----+-----

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.08 sec(s).

orientdb> update liked set class = 'Liked', ID = '1234', out = #12:0, in = #13:0, extra = "updated data" UPSERT WHERE ID = "1234"

Updated record(s) '1' in 0.084000 sec(s).

orientdb> select * from Liked

----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----
#   |@RID |@CLASS|out  |in   |class|ID  |extra
----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----
0   |#14:0|Liked |#12:0|#13:0|null |null|null 
1   |#14:1|Liked |#12:0|#13:0|Liked|1234|data 
----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----

2 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.085 sec(s).
```

Lastly, query from gremlin.sh:

```
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[#14:0][#12:0-Used->#13:0]
==>e[#14:1][#12:0-Used->#13:0]
```

The edge is clearly there, but when I traverse it:

```
gremlin> g.v('#16:0').outE
==>e[#14:0][#12:0-Liked->#13:0]
```

'#14:1' should be there, but it's not.

Comment: Seems if I switch to using "Create Edge" it works better, but then I loose the Upsert

Comment: After some research, it looks like I shouldn't be calling the update method directly, as it has this exact problem where the edge is linked to the vertices but the vertices aren't linked to the edge.  A new command "update edge" is being introduced in 2.2: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/1114#issuecomment-159255742